# Las pruebas unitarias se aplican sólo al modelo y no en el controlador?

Tags: laravel, mvc, ruby-on-rails

En la arquitectura MVC, las pruebas unitarias se realizan si y solo si en el modelo y no en el controlador ? 
Espero que me puedan ayudar ya que me confunde esto, estoy trabajando con rails y laravel y por buenas practicas nos dicen que todo debe hacerse en el modelo y no en el controlador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor dicho sería: *las pruebas unitarias nunca deben ir en tu controlador*.

En *Rails* comunmente se relaciona a las pruebas unitarias con los modelos,  sin embargo no siempre es es así, depende de la organización de tu código pues podrías, por ejemplo, utilizar *servicios* para encapsular cierta lógica de negocio que no pertenece ni al controlador ni al modelo.

Entonces, hablando de *pruebas **unitarias*** estas deben de hacerse en cada unidad de código independiente que deseas probar, en *Rails* generalmente siendo en los modelos y **nunca** en el controlador<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Esto no quiere decir que no pruebes tus controladores, debes probarlos con lo que *Rails* llama *pruebas funcionales*; para conocer más detalles puedes revisar la [guía de pruebas de Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html).</sup>

Comment: Tengo una aplicación webservice en rails con varios endpoints, unos son simples crud, otros generan archivos pdf, excel, csv y entrega una url, otros le envío ciertos parámetros y realizan cálculos financieros por cliente para saber estado de cuenta, entonces a esos endpoints tendría que aplicarles pruebas funcionales o me equivoco ?

Comment: @ErickAvalos Idealmente los controladores donde defines cada _endpoint_ no contienen lógica de negocio, simplemente reciben el request, solicitan los datos (generalmente a través de un objeto) y envían los datos recibidos. Los objetos que el controlador utiliza para obtener la información solicitada deberán tener el código fuera del controlador (generalmente en Modelos). Entonces, para probar los _endpoints_ utilizarías pruebas funcionales y para probar los objetos/modelos utilizarías pruebas unitarias.